# Need to create abundance values using two columns from different sized data frames based on a common variable in the two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, summarize

I have two data frames "Phylum.MYS" (68 x 5) and "Benthic" (13 x 5)

My goal is to make an "abundance" column in "Phylum.MYS" --> "Phylum.MYS$abundace"

This column would hold the abundance values of each variable in "Phylum.MYS$Phylum" by doing --> "Phylum.MYS$count" / "Benthic$Count" based on if "Phlyum$Month_year" == "Benthic$Month_Year.y"

Appreciate the help!

```
> head(Phylum.MYS)
  Month_Year     Phylum Count Salinity     Date
1    2000-06   Nemertea     6 18.27130 Jun-2000
2    2000-06  Phoronida     2 18.27130 Jun-2000
3    2000-06   Annelida    45 18.27130 Jun-2000
4    2000-06 Arthropoda     9 18.27130 Jun-2000
5    2000-06   Mollusca     2 18.27130 Jun-2000
6    2000-09   Nemertea     2 20.72727 Sep-2000
> head(Benthic)
      Date Month_Year.x Salinity Month_Year.y Count
1 Jun-2000      2000-06 18.27130      2000-06    66
2 Sep-2000      2000-09 20.72727      2000-09    61
3 Jun-2001      2001-06 18.33818      2001-06    62
4 Sep-2001      2001-09 20.95091      2001-09   115
5 Jun-2002      2002-06 20.74917      2002-06    65
6 Jun-2003      2003-06 15.62000      2003-06    81
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(data.table)
Phylum.MYS <- data.table(Month_Year = c('2000-06','2000-06','2000-06','2000-06','2000-06','2000-09'),
                         Phylum = c('Nemertea','Phoronida','Annelida','Arthropoda','Mollusca','Nemertea'),
                         Count = c(6,2,45,9,2,2))

Benthic <- data.table(Month_Year.y = c('2000-06','2000-09','2001-06','2001-09','2002-06','2003-06'),
                      Count = c(66,61,62,115,65,81))

Phylum.MYS <- merge(Phylum.MYS, Benthic, by.x = 'Month_Year', by.y = 'Month_Year.y',all = TRUE)

Phylum.MYS[, abundance := (Count.x/Count.y)]
Phylum.MYS
```